# SSRS: How can I bind a diagram to a vertical title bar (tablix)?

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

This will be my first question at this forum :-) However, I am currently having problem with one of my SSRS reports. The report consists of a graph/diagram. I have put a vertical title bar with some measures below the graph. This is a quite long title bar which requires the user to vertically scroll on the bar to the right in order to see the last measures from the SSAS cube.

When they do this the graph/diagram is fixed on its "normal position".

Is it existing any way to "bind" the graph to the title bar so it will follow when the user is scrolling to the right ?

Thanks for all kind of input! I am totally lost here :)

Nicklas

Comment: I'm afraid it is not possible, SSRS doesn't include gestures as 'Dynamic titles' or similars. How long is the scroll? have you consider to place additional title in the end of the scroll ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but this is **not** a feature in SSRS.

---

However I would do as @GilPeretz suggested. In this workaround I'd:

1. Remove the current title;
2. Reduce the chart size; and
3. Position two or three titles where appropriate.